# WPF Application Display PDF Document

Tags: wpf, pdf

Is there a Way I can display PDF Document within a WPF app? I was able to do on a Windows XP Box with Acrobat 8.x installed. But on windows 7 with Acrobat 9.x installed, those ActiveX controls are not available anymore... Is there an alternate control I should be looking for?

Comment: Thanks All.. My problem with this issue is not yet resolved... Problem looks like with the Acrobat.. or may be x64 Framework or both.. but the use of AcroPdf activeX control will display document on WindowsXP, Windows7 x86 (32bit) but throws an exception, "Class NOT Registered" on Windows 7 x64 (even if the application is compiled for x86). Same with the use of Browser control also. This is the current stage of Narrowdown of the problem. Any help or direction to resolve this is appreciated..

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/pdfviewernet/

Comment: Thanks Stu. These answers definitely help someone who is having similar issues with PDF viewing. pdfviewernet is a great attempt to create an opensource alternative. However it is still in the very premature state.

Comment: BTW.. I solved the problem by compiling the application as x86 only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://hugeonion.com/2009/04/06/displaying-a-pdf-file-within-a-wpf-application/

Comment: Thanks Stu. The problem is that the Control which is AxAcroPDF is not available with Acrobat 9.x. This is the source of the problem.

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/31ea1846-d4e7-4a9e-91ee-dad87e8d1fb7/  shows an alternative, using a web browser control. Although I shudder to think of the overhead.

Comment: I tried that too.. but PDF is not being opened in the browser control.. I tried putting in some images in the HTML and that did not work either.. Looks like some thing has to be done to show embedded content to show in the browser control

Comment: It loads images from a URL like Google.com though.. but not from a local uri.

Comment: Then I give up. Might be better to abandon Adobe altogether then: http://www.atalasoft.com/company/press-releases/atalasoft-releases-free-image-viewing-and-processi

Comment: Thanks All.. My problem with this issue is not yet resolved... Problem looks like with the Acrobat.. or may be x64 Framework or both.. but the use of AcroPdf activeX control will display document on WindowsXP, Windows7 x86 (32bit) but throws an exception, "Class NOT Registered" on Windows 7 x64 (even if the application is compiled for x86). Same with the use of Browser control also. This is the current stage of Narrowdown of the problem. Any help or direction to resolve this is appreciated..

Comment: From my reading the free viewer from Altasoft is Windows Forms and not WPF.  They have a WPF SDK Viewer but I don't think that is free.  Can always download the free Photo product and see if it will host in WPF.  Integrating with Adobe products is never easy.

Comment: This method works with AcrobatX (SP1 or Later) on Windows 7 x64 when the application is targeted for x86. It did not work with the base install though. I am using AcrobatX Standard Edition. Thanks for all the help.